# Best way to get script output into elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I wrote a Python program to parse an internal website to retrieve a number of metrics. The script spits out something like this:

12 456 785.3 .12 23145

Each value contains a unique performance metric. I'm now looking for ways to get this data into elasticsearch so I can start making use of it. There are several input plug-ins:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html

And I'm curious which one folks are using to get script data into elasticsearch? Should I funnel it to syslog and grok it from there? Anyone using meetup? Any other solutions that I may be missing? I read numerous posts / websites and the solutions they proposed seem extremely complicated for this super simple job.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a custom script for just this task, I'd change the script to generate JSON and use the Python Elastic SDK to insert the document in Elastic. Alternatively, your script could output JSON to stdout and you could have a simple bash script that does a curl to insert the document in Elasticsearch.